# plaintext with private PHP

Tags: php, encryption, hash, cryptography, phpseclib

For this question, Im using Asymmetric encryption, I have private key which I want to use to sign data and public key which will verify the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Include library
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

// Create an Instance
$rsa  = new Crypt_RSA();

//Get Private Key
$privatekey = file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\encrypt\private.txt');

// Message to be signed
$plaintext = "<Transaction><No>1344</No></Transaction>";

$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1); // Set signing signature 
$encrypted = $rsa->sign($hashed); // Sign Data
$signature = base64_encode($encrypted); // Encode to base64 the signed Data
```

PKCS1 signatures sha1 hashes by default. The code you posted is essentially making an sha1 hash of an sha1 hash.